# Floating decimal point type in Haxe

Tags: decimal, haxe

Is there floating decimal point type in Haxe (similar to decimal.Decimal in Python, i.e. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_854-1987)? For the application I have float is not an option due to possible precision problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anything like that exists in the standard library, apart from target-specific externs such as `java.math.BigDecimal`. So if you want a cross-platform solution, you would need a third-party library.

One that comes to mind is [`thx.Decimal`](https://github.com/fponticelli/thx.core/blob/master/src/thx/Decimal.hx) from the [`thx.core`](https://github.com/fponticelli/thx.core) library. Having a look at the [associated test cases](https://github.com/fponticelli/thx.core/blob/master/test/thx/TestDecimal.hx) may be helpful since there's not much documentation.